# Android databinding not triggered in jetpack compose android view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-databinding

I am trying to mix Jetpack compose with some legacy code that we have. Was hoping that it would be an easy fix since this is a part of the app that is rarely used. The problem at hand is that i am trying to add legacy view that has databinding to an already made compose view

#### The View

```
@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
class TimeAndDateScroller @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    timePickerViewModel: TimeAndDatePickerViewModel,
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    var binding: ViewTimePickerBinding? = null

    init {
        binding = ViewTimePickerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true).apply {
            this.viewModel = timePickerViewModel
        }
    }
}
```

#### Compose View

```
AndroidView(
    factory = {
        TimeAndDateScroller(it, timePickerViewModel = viewModel).apply {
            layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        }
    }, update = {

    }
)
```

#### ViewModel and XML

The view model is passed down correctly as far as i understand. But the values inside the view model is not triggering the listening xml view

```
val isPickerEnabled: LiveData<Boolean> = selectedOption
        .map {
            it != TimeParamType.NOW
        }
        .asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main)
```

The value above is found in the view model. But the corresponding xml listener is never triggered

```
android:alpha="@{viewModel.isPickerEnabled() ? 1f : 0.4f}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the viewModel you would normally add:

```
val isPickerEnabledValue = ObservableField<Boolean>()


init {
    isPickerEnabledValue.set(false)
}
```

Then this will be updated based on the live data in the activity/fragment:

```
vm.isPickerEnabledLiveData.observe(this, isEnabled ->
        vm.isPickerEnabledValue.set(isEnabled)
    }
)
```

And then in the xml it would be:

```
android:alpha="@{viewModel.isPickerEnabledValue ? 1f : 0.4f}"
```

So since this is hybrid with compose, instead of the ObservableField we would use:

```
var isPickerEnabledValue: State<Boolean> = stateOf(false)
```

and then in Compose you could use:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = {
        viewModel.isPickerEnabledValue = viewModel.isPickerEnabledLiveData.observeAsState()
```

The key is you can't get data out of live data directly, but have to observer it in some way, while ObservableField or State can be used directly.